# R RMySQL cannot read myconfig.cnf

Tags: r

I'm trying to read the file myconfig.sys from MySQL with R RMySQL without success.
The objective is to save the *user* and *password* is this file.

I did the file in MySQL with mysql_config_editor:

```
Shell> mysql_config_editor set –login-path=test_db –host=localhost –user=root --password
```

To simplify I placed myconfig.cnf in the root directory `c:/`.

In R with RMySQL I did the follow:

```
a <- "c:/mylogin.cnf"
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), default.file=a, group='test_db', user=NULL, password=NULL)
```

When R run, the session is aborted, making it extremely difficult to know what happened.

> My system: Win 7 prof – 64 b R 3.2.0 RMySQL 0.10.9 RStudio 0.99.441
>   MySQL 57 MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Windows version 6.3.6 CE
>   build 511 (64 bit)

Comment: Could this be helpful? https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/issues/102

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but is other trouble.

Comment: I tried it with XAMPP and RMySQL. It is probably because you are missing some configurations. When I copied the default `my.cnf`, added the username and password to it and set the `default.file` argument to the location of the new `my.cnf`, then it worked.

Comment: Follow the steps to solve this:

Comment: 1- open the file C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/my.ini  2- Add two lines in this file                               [client]
no-beep
# pipe
# socket=0.0
user=root  #added line
password=mypassword  #added line
port=3306
3- a <- "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/my.ini"
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), default.file=a, group='test_db', user=NULL, password=NULL)